# Definition of $\Omega_X(x_1+ \dots + x_n)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface such that $x_i$ are distinct prime divisors on $X$.

I for some reason am having difficulty finding the definition of $\Omega_X(x_1+ \dots + x_n)$.

My guess is that we can describe $\Omega_X(x_1+ \dots + x_n)$ as the set of rational sections of $\Omega_X$ such that $v_{x_i}(f) \ge -1$.

Is the the correct definition?

Comment: You mean that the $x_i$ prime divisors and different, right?

Comment: Yeah of course, I will edit to be less vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct, this is indeed the sheaf of meromorphic $1$-forms, with at most one pole at each $x_i$ (assuming the $x_i$ are different).

This makes sense for any divisor $D$, and $\Omega_X(D)$ is the set of rational sections $\omega$ with $\text{div}(\omega) + D \geq 0$.